# Priority queue with update ability

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am trying to implement a queue of employees in an efficient complexity.

When I insert an employee to the queue I provide its ID number and its score.
I want to maintain a queue ordered by the employees' scores in ascending order.

So far the problem can be solved using a priority queue implemented by a binary heap, but I need to be able to remove employees from the queue and update an employee by its ID number.
As far as I know binary heap does not support an efficient way of removing or updating an element.

**Update** - O(n) for searching the element + O(1) for updating it.

**Remove** - O(n) for searching the element + O(nlg(n)) for rebuilding the heap.

Is there a more appropriate data structure for the problem?

Comment: You can do both in O(log n) with ordered tree

Comment: If I build the tree by the score values, how can I find an employee by its ID and remove/update it under O(n)?

Comment: build by pairs of {score, id} instead of just score

Comment: You'd probably be better off with a fully ordered structure, like a binary search tree, finger search tree, or skip list

Comment: To update "score" you just need to move employee either up or down the heap, depending on how the score changes.  To remove employee, replace by last entry in heap, and move that employee either up or down the heap.  Either way: O(lg(n)) -- after the O(n) to find the employee.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it fairly easy with some extra memory.

The easiest way: Just add duplicate IDs to the tree. Then keep a hash-set (or bitmap if the IDs are ordered) to know if you've already returned a certain ID (to skip the duplicates that come out later).

A bit harder: Keep a hash-map from IDs to locations in the heap. You need to update the hash-map every-time you touch the heap. Since you know where the element is you can update it's score in O(1) then push or pop the node to restore the heap (this should be O(logN)).

Another simple alternative: If the scores only decrease (assuming you have a max-heap), then you don't do anything for the update. When you want to pop the top you recompute the score, if it should be changed you push the node down. If it's still at the top you can remove it, if not, you go back to recomputing the score of the top element. The updates are still O(logN), but you incur the cost when you try take the top element.

Also for removing an arbitrary element the complexity should be O(logN). You swap it with the last element, then call push the position.